# Android - Hiding the Status Bar on PreferenceFragment

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-activity, preferenceactivity

I currently have a PreferenceActivity class which contains a PreferenceFragment.
The PreferenceActivity doesn't show the statusbar, only the actionbar.
But when i click an option to open a 'sub-menu', the statusbar appears and 'pushes everything down'.

My goal is that both the PreferenceActivity and its sub menus (PreferenceFrament) would show the ActionBar without the status bar.

AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<activity
    android:name="com.myapp.SettingsActivity"
    android:label="@string/title_settings"
    android:theme="@style/mySettingsTheme" >
</activity>
```

The relevant styles:

```
<style name="mySettingsTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light">
    <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/mySettingsActionBar</item>
</style>

<style name="mySettingsActionBar" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar">
    <item name="android:titleTextStyle">@style/mySettingsActionBarTitleTextStyle</item>
</style>

<style name="mySettingsActionBarTitleTextStyle" parent="@android:style/TextAppearance.Holo.Widget.ActionBar.Title">
    <item name="android:textColor">#FFFFFF</item>
</style>
```

I'm settings the flags to FullScreen using this code

```
getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
```

During onCreate on PreferenceActivity class to remove the statusbar, but it doesn't work on the fragment.
I've also tried creating a manifest field for that fragment, but nothing helped.

Can anyone help?

Comment: Do you want to show the ActionBar? Because in that case you should remove the layout flags. Or, if you do not want to use the actionbar, you should not use a theme with an actionbar (use .NoActionBar instead)

Comment: @Mdlc Thank you for your comment. I do want to see the ActionBar, but not the Status bar. I'll update the question to make it more clear :)

Comment: Perhaps the fragment is restoring the default window manager flags. 

Have you tried adding this code to the onCreate of the fragment?

Comment: @jwv Yes, i've tried that but it doesn't work.